# How to run .exe application with paramenters from java?

Tags: java

I want to run .exe application with two parameters.Its VB .exe application its need two parameters to execute ? I tried with create .cmd file to execute .exe application, its working good.

Please see the which code running .cmd file.
    start ***xx.exe ./aa.txt,2012***

Same procedure following in java, but giving error...
Please find the below small java program.

```
public class Invoke
{
 public static void main(String as[])
 Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
 Processp=null;
 try

 {
  String s="...complie.exe";
  String d="...de.txt";
  String l="...foldername";
  p=r.exec(s,d,l);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   }
```

Please advise...

Comment: I really can't understand what do you want. Do you want to execute just an .exe application or .exe app, .txt file..?

Comment: .exe application along with .txt,folder want run through java program

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to start `jEdit` program and some txt file from Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Invoke {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files/jEdit/jedit.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad C:/Program Files/TechSmith/Camtasia Studio 7/TSCCinst.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```